# can names of objects in a picture be retrieved from a google search by image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, cbir

i was working on a project where in i take photos of a particular object and i wanted that object to be recognized.So i was thinking of using google image search so that i get the name of the object 
however i noticed that image search fails to name the objects i upload on the search. only similar images are displayed
can anyone suggest other possible search engines which may help?
the main reason i am resorting to google image search is that i don't want the application to be restricted to a few hundreds of images in a database

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Google Image Search only retrieves those images that are similar to the query. It doesn't give you the names of the objects. If you want these, you need to look at object **classification**.  There is currently no publicly available search engine that can facilitate this.  However, there has been lots of research. Check: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gary/pubs/robust-classification-final.pdf and http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2013/papers/Dong_Subcategory-Aware_Object_Classification_2013_CVPR_paper.pdf .  Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_categorization_from_image_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload image to [Google Image Search](http://images.google.com/imghp), it will try to guess what's portrayed there (will be a Google search link right under your image).

[Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZit8DZmNpyVK9EadGjyMefHwJk86LQb68i-RfzKLUL929w79eROA_17in1Vyrv_1q3e5r1mYUyYbvrJEOG5ERhAe9B3r-VkQFzp0G0mek3-4KAjKQbXCxCvkrx5sMvzjujUWfynGARgWD8uInKzNHx2sWR0GeCkKIlhHrXtxUPds9x9QCN54R0zuhTGn8VHgyvwX_1MhIHLiVzFVqXZ8kRh5qVs8gOHktojYf8HNy4OZth3Wo8RHsSzK110Qm-AuEyzTYW2TV6D6Ex_1X1TtamkkMizXEUu0x2eERq9gbbOHnoIVSvUZCeVld9s8m3J2_1RROALEQe5aqUhFwX4QP4cKQ_1uhZp1QcE_10z5wZeH8vhtav_1jU73e0uY_1sqajZJ1o42gFD-ahYK6i0mT9E2pGt4HPwWVkASMGu8FgqXKyVhpIccbg1Ki8hNlNCs5yDrqqA3nLOIHtF6QrY9zRJWeC-ZO5bq53NUZZoZcPMbJkWeHy1IBk63w_1galZ8-DAuaJLvwzJm_18JGzMT2K2m1sm6GM6-cZZDTF6ZokKxuBdT5_16y9AKnIFlJV0Rq4m1ILrUBhZPDhTgyxxhAMxTj6Vuk6G50iq1ovjlEmqHtLLUIOrA3pb_1LmCm_1-r9MAvbzPt3xVVcRevseDVC3o3V11r0TfUkZF19KfVSUAdu1HddlDH98teILahAPKflhJ8F9J1HQo7as0pjaODeC1qU-3-6hf1BoPQeWOHQI_11i63QDfDh8LLq60jb3-XDPcEONvlMQX4kc7_1aX_1dj5bXm7BrFVIZxiL6VtPn6hVuWtJZ9bdw6sfgI50dTGwIv_17nGVNE0hFPcaaL9-UjDJyTblWLdwnBwdrb8DbIPZuBftyuXFP47YvWFA7QECZf14HcQoTsl9aKxxQj5rhF3tGgQn-bUACI0WjQs1ZviFSgYPM1ct6GPZebaOuGthSc45innXfFlxnfE_1celzRvnIb20gHHBoQRye2SJhHUrwKTHQd68Lx99Cwxtx5xaN0jCKI2B5pQgsapiL8Mw6ft6coN6fyrrgUk2SR6cm_18nR9KxlBeDv4zhTSz0RBcddQiKlElZCP-bbyKQf8QZ13EwB12kQXSVZGE6ewv-Yx8Cgj87xUknfxwd7doPTCet5PlYE0zMuLAGnMYzN1mspAVlXqdySUuWqLT-RfU1Czrx46FKASYiJ87QKCwhosRmSelqi4vOSjLgwChvPlds0QWHoBJ4RCSfl-0lk0jzPrglXnQ6cSdJ4ffPbfJkwTrqJeCDsbVI-w8ngPxsitvB-ENtselizH9I7SFHNV4P3AejDvaIYgt2tnN3g637PrN2_1V3eOPWBwlvcZ1-nyVyIVaLUOtvq10j_1ESx5viXqF1XswSot_1UY-I_1AsamKOCXs15CoPkNZyZQctuGKcqhLq2n6fD0yl6RXSQI4FPiFIkQiPgkr59uhtDiINPp9p7L1b7TWcIwt0TBt7nsMkUh-tXC42boxbJSowPKQSuYM_1wRygMKg&gws_rd=ssl) what I've uploaded (trimmed phone camera photo).